# UNIX creating a function that imitates the rm error conditions?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am stuck on this part of my project. How would I create a function to where if I put "sh remove filename" in the command line, it would act the same as "rm filename" and tests its error conditions and display the same error messages as the rm command? This is what I have so far but I don't think its right:

Comment: By using `sh` in your alias, do you intend to spawn a subshell?

Comment: No. We didn't learn about subshells. I just wanted to make "sh remove" imitate "rm" and making an alias is the only way I know how to do it. Not sure how else you would do it

Answer (score 0):

You've probably misunderstood the question which is summarized in :

> if I put "sh remove filename" in the command line, it would act the
>   same as "rm filename"

Create a script named `remove` with the following content

```
# No shebang
# You need to check if a parameter is passed, omitting that for brevity
rm "$@" # Double quoting is crucial
```

Save it and run it as

```
sh remove "filename"
# Here sh which is probably a link to bash will interpret the contents in remove
```

Comment: Thank you. My script name is remove too. All my code is in a script named "remove". All I need to do is input sh remove "filename" in the shell and I should be good? I don't need a function or alias to do what is it asking me to do?

Comment: `All I need to do is input sh remove "filename" in the shell and I should be good?` For the simple task, you sure don't need the big piece of code you put in the question. Just the little bit that I posted should be put in the script and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated